# Memory error while loading CIFAR10 training data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, jupyter-notebook

I was solving assignment 2 ([link](http://cs231n.github.io/assignment2/)) of Andrej Karpathy's course on Neural network. The programming environment is ipython notebook. When i am trying to load CIFAR10 data I am repeatedly getting memory error. I tried to google any solution but nothing worked. Please help me here.

```html
from cs231n.data_utils import load_CIFAR10

def get_CIFAR10_data(num_training=49000, num_validation=1000, num_test=1000):
    """
    Load the CIFAR-10 dataset from disk and perform preprocessing to prepare
    it for the two-layer neural net classifier. These are the same steps as
    we used for the SVM, but condensed to a single function.  
    """
    # Load the raw CIFAR-10 data
    cifar10_dir = 'cs231n/datasets/cifar-10-batches-py'
    X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = load_CIFAR10(cifar10_dir)
        
    # Subsample the data
    mask = range(num_training, num_training + num_validation)
    X_val = X_train[mask]
    y_val = y_train[mask]
    mask = range(num_training)
    X_train = X_train[mask]
    y_train = y_train[mask]
    mask = range(num_test)
    X_test = X_test[mask]
    y_test = y_test[mask]

    # Normalize the data: subtract the mean image
    mean_image = np.mean(X_train, axis=0)
    X_train -= mean_image
    X_val -= mean_image
    X_test -= mean_image

    # Reshape data to rows
    X_train = X_train.reshape(num_training, -1)
    X_val = X_val.reshape(num_validation, -1)
    X_test = X_test.reshape(num_test, -1)

    return X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, X_test, y_test


# Invoke the above function to get our data.
X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, X_test, y_test = get_CIFAR10_data()
print 'Train data shape: ', X_train.shape
print 'Train labels shape: ', y_train.shape
print 'Validation data shape: ', X_val.shape
print 'Validation labels shape: ', y_val.shape
print 'Test data shape: ', X_test.shape
print 'Test labels shape: ', y_test.shape
```

```html
import cPickle as pickle
import numpy as np
import os

def load_CIFAR_batch(filename):
  """ load single batch of cifar """
  with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    datadict = pickle.load(f)
    X = datadict['data']
    Y = datadict['labels']
    X = X.reshape(10000, 3, 32, 32).transpose(0,2,3,1).astype("float")
    Y = np.array(Y)
    return X, Y

def load_CIFAR10(ROOT):
  """ load all of cifar """
  xs = []
  ys = []
  for b in range(1,6):
    f = os.path.join(ROOT, 'data_batch_%d' % (b, ))
    X, Y = load_CIFAR_batch(f)
    xs.append(X)
    ys.append(Y)    
  Xtr = np.concatenate(xs)
  Ytr = np.concatenate(ys)
  del X, Y
  Xte, Yte = load_CIFAR_batch(os.path.join(ROOT, 'test_batch'))
  return Xtr, Ytr, Xte, Yte
```

Comment: Have you solved this?  I'm having a similar issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is facing the same issue on windows os please install x64 python distribution. Memory usage of x86 distribution is capped at 2GB.